# How to implement delay in JdbcSinkConnector?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I set the (connection.backoff.ms, retry.backoff.ms) parameter to 5 minutes, and expect that after sending from kafka to the disconnected database, the retry will be 5 minutes. But after restarting the database, the message from kafka immediately arrives and not after 5 minutes. Maybe some other parameter is responsible for this?

I'm using this docker images https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/tree/master/kafka-to-database

It's my connector config:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/jdbc_postgres/config \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
"connection.url":"jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres",
"topics":"test01",
"key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
"value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://schema-registry:8081",
"connection.user":"postgres",
"connection.password":"postgres",
"auto.create":true,
"auto.evolve":true,
"insert.mode":"upsert",
"pk.mode":"record_key",
"pk.fields":"MESSAGE_KEY",
"transforms":"Filter",
"transforms.Filter.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Filter",
"transforms.Filter.predicate":"DropNull",
"predicates":"DropNull",
"predicates.DropNull.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.predicates.RecordIsTombstone",
"errors.log.enable":"true",
"errors.tolerance":"all",
"errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name":"dead_test01",
"errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor":"-1",
"connection.backoff.ms":"300000"
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `consumer.override.` prefix to set either of those for the consumer, but that's only the connection to the broker, not the database.

You cannot delay a Kafka consumer polling loop in Connect API.

Answer (score 0):

There is a confusion here between `connection.backoff.ms` and `retry.backoff.ms`.

`connection.backoff.ms` is the one you should use to control time delay with the db in case of communication failure.

while `retry.backoff.ms` is just to control the delay before retrying a task inside the connector in case of any processing failure.

It worth to mention that, if you started your connector and the db link got broken, when you check the status of your connector (`curl localhost:8083/connector/connector_name/status`), you will see the task is in `RUNNING` state, which means the `retry.backoff.ms` will not get into action by any means.

Getting back to `connection.backoff.ms`, assuming the below sequence of events:

```
 DB up              connector up         DB Down  
   |----------------------|-----------------|******************************|--------
                                            |------------------------------|
                                        connector                      Next retry time
                                        will fail
                                        (here, you should see in the logs, something like 
                            "Unable to connect to database on attempt 1/3. Will retry in X ms." X=connection.backoff.ms)
```

If you bring up the DB anytime during the `****` the connector shouldn't take any action until the next retry time comes in, and if you see such behavior, make sure that you are not bringing up the db exactly on the time of the retry action.

Comment: With use my config (connection.backoff.ms) i get next error:
"name":"jdbc_postgres",
"connector":{
"state":"RUNNING",
"worker_id":"kafka-connect:8083"
},
"tasks":[
{
"id":0,
"state":"FAILED",
"worker_id":"kafka-connect:8083",
"trace":"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception. at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:614) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration
}
],
"type":"sink"